# Expressing Integral as Power Series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I am asked to express the given function that involves an improper integral in a form $f_n(z)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{\frac{1}{z}e^x+z}dx$ in terms of power series centered at x = 0.
My attempt was to express $e^x$ in terms of its power series, such that:
$e^x =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $ but in that case the sum terms is in the denominator and I am incapable of combining it with the independent value of the numerator to combine it into a single sum. Am I doing it right? I am sort of confused on this one. I've got to a final step of $f_n(z)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}+z}$. I am not sure how to reduce this whole expression into a series from here, as I've only learnt how to get rid of the integral if the sum term is in the numerator.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that $|z|\leq 1$. If not, then things become more complicated.

$$f_n(z)=\frac{z}{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x+z^2}dx$$

$$f_n(z)=\frac{z}{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}x^{n-1}}{1+e^{-x}z^2}dx$$

$$f_n(z)=\frac{z}{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k e^{-kx}z^{2k}dx$$

$$f_n(z)=\frac{z}{(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{2k} \int_0^\infty x^{n-1}  e^{-(k+1)x}dx$$

$$f_n(z)=\frac{z}{(n-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k z^{2k}}{(k+1)^n} \int_0^\infty t^{n-1}  e^{-t}dt$$

$$\color{blue}{f_n(z)=z \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k z^{2k}}{(k+1)^n}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much Yuriy! You're a life-saver. However, could you please clarify why the (n - 1)! part in the denominator was eliminated in the last part along with the integral? Thank you!

Comment: @ErnestasBlaževič, simple: they are equal by definition. Look up Gamma function, main definition

Comment: Yuriy S, thank you for everything. You are the best! I clearly see the whole logic from here. I actually made a typo and it was supposed to be (1/z)e^x + 1 in the denominator, but I was able to apply your logic for my corrected version of the function. Truly appreciate your work and explanation, thank you so much!